# Operators for new-style classes

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, operator-overloading

Could anyone explain to me why `A()+A()` does give an error, but `B()+B()` works as expected? I came across this when I was writing a larger piece of code, but this seems to be the smallest code necessary to reproduce it.

```
from types import MethodType

D = {'__add__': lambda x, y: "".join((repr(x), repr(y)))}

class A(object):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item == '__coerce__':
            raise AttributeError()
        return MethodType(D[item], self)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "A"

class B():
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item == '__coerce__':
            raise AttributeError()
        return MethodType(D[item], self)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "B"

try:
    A()+A()
except Exception as e:
    print e

B()+B()
```

Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because new style classes never invoke `__coerce__` with binary operators. Also for special methods `__getattr__` is never invoked in new style classes: From Data model [coercion rules](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#coercion-rules):

> New-style classes (those derived from object) never invoke the
>   `__coerce__()` method in response to a binary operator; the only time `__coerce__()` is invoked is when the built-in function `coerce()` is called.